# Aurelia ViewModel without a view

Tags: aurelia, aurelia-templating

i want to have a route to a popup dialog.
I created a viewmodel with @noView

```
import {noView} from "aurelia-framework";

@noView()
export class MyViewModel{
     ...
}
```

but this leads to this error:

```
aurelia-logging-console.js:54 ERROR [app-router] TypeError: Cannot set property 'bindingContext' of null
```

In my opinion showing the popup from my navbar.ts is not suitable as i don't like to have such code in the navbar, i rather would have it on a place more suitable.

What is the best way to show a popup from navbar without losing the current content of the page so basically show it from anywhere and also with no code in navbar.ts at all.

Is there a better and nicer way to achive this?
Should i rethink my page layout?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think I'm following you. Would you mind creating a gist.run example?

Comment: Well, let's say someone wants to show a "signup for newletter" popup. How would you implement it? And let's say the button which opens the popup is visible on all pages.

Comment: @AshleyGrant I will try to make a gist.

Comment: @paranoxx you don't need to make this a composed view model just create a module that creates the popup and import / inject it to any view model code you want it to show up on.

Comment: @PWKad My way of thinking was way too complicated. Thanks, that's perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look up for [event aggregator](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/cheat-sheet/10) in this situation.
Where clicking a link or pressing a button will send an event and you can handle this event straight in the app.ts
So you will require your subscription behavior only in app and send an event to activate the popup from anywhere you want.

gl hf (-: